# Alterar lagura e altura da célula do Excel utilizando xlwt

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, python-2.7

Preciso alterar altura e largura da célula do Excel estou utilizando a biblioteca `xlwt`. Não achei nenhuma referencia, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode definir a largura e altura de uma determinada linha ou coluna usando as propriedades `width` e `height` da folha.

Veja um exemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'utf-8')
""" Define o nome da folha """
sheet = book.add_sheet('SOpt')

""" Define a altura da segunda linha """
sheet.row(1).height_mismatch = True
sheet.row(1).height = 256 * 2

""" Define a largura da segunda coluna - 30 caracteres """
sheet.col(1).width = 256 * 30

""" Escreve na segunda linha da segunda coluna - B2 """
sheet.write(1, 1, 'Stack overflow em Português!')

book.save('sopt.xls')
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]